# Purpose/usage of Docker build -t flag vs Docker tag

Tags: docker

Want to clarify my understanding as I am confused after studying the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)

For command `docker build -t` the definition stated that

> -t flag "Name and optionally a tag in the 'name:tag' format"

We then run `docker tag xxx` to "Create a tag TARGET_IMAGE that refers to SOURCE_IMAGE" before we can push to the registry.

What is the difference of the functionality of 2 tagging here? Is the `-t` flag tags as the name of the build (image), which then `docker tag` that on top of the 'tagged' build before pushing it?

I tried searching online and questions here but couldn't find any explanation.

Comment: There is no difference between `docker tag` and the `-t` flag. The `-t` flag is just shorthand instead of building the image and running `docker tag` afterwards to tag the image id.

Comment: in short: `docker build -t name:tag .` == `docker build . && docker tag <id_of_precedent_buid_written_on_screen> name:tag`

Comment: thanks for clarifying, why is there many guides that specify both then?
For example, AWS guide "Push commands for ECR"
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/getting-started-cli.html#cli-create-image and within console.

Step3: Build the Docker image from your Dockerfile. "docker build -t hello-world ."

and after that with "docker tag hello-world:latest aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hello-world:latest". Is there difference in purpose for the 2 steps?

Comment: does that mean if we use `docker build -t` flag, we can skip the command step `docker tag`?

Comment: Your example first tags the image with a name in your local registry (`hello-world`). Then it tags it with a name in a remote registry (`aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hello-world:latest`). That allows you to `push` the image to that registry.

Comment: thanks for all the comments for clarifying. i finally understood this with help of https://youtu.be/vWSRWpOPHws?t=354 :) so now i understand that `docker build -t name:tag` is to tag the image locally in docker. whereas using the `tag` command is renaming with other repo (other than dockerhub) for docker to recognize.. as mentioned by comments above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of (credits to) comments above and clear explanation in this video https://youtu.be/vWSRWpOPHws?t=354,

I cleared my doubts finally. `docker build -t name:tag` is to tag the image locally in docker. whereas using the `tag` command is renaming with other repo (other than dockerhub) for docker to recognize.. as mentioned by comments above and in the video.

I also tried a shortcut to verify if that works, so apparently we can shortcut with `docker build -t <aws-ecr-uri-or-other-remote-repo-uri>/<same-name-as-your-app>:tag` that combine both steps in one, then you can proceed to push it to AWS ECR with `docker push`

Just a note apart from the question. AWS ECR repo == 1 image each. (for different versions). So if you have different images, you have to create different repository in ECR for each.

Comment: I was confused about this too as it is a bit different with ECR. The video helped to clarify.